# Should I use a question mark or a period here?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

"Why don't you come over here? Then we could talk."

Hi. I can't figure out whether it is correct to use a question mark where I have or if it should be a period instead. What is correct? Is it optional? Thank you.

Comment: It's a question, so question mark is correct.

Comment: Use the question mark. We use question marks after all questions, including rhetorical ones, and requests disguised as questions.

Comment: Would you please give some more detailed context?

Answer (score 1):

Use a question mark.

This is a rhetorical question, we don't expect the person to answer the question. Nevertheless it would normally be punctuated with a question mark. In speech it would also have question intonation (rising slightly).

Sometimes an author will break this rule in order to indicate that a particular phrase was spoken with a particular intonation.

> Angrily his mother said "Will you put that down!"

It would have been okay to use a question mark in that case, but using an exclamation mark indicates that the mother did not use question intonation.

However, the usual rule is "end all questions with a question mark".